# document.getElementById('input-ID').value - for an input (!) - returns undefined

Tags: javascript, regex

My strength is not in Javascript. My "simple" mountain to climb right now is to get the value of the input! I keep getting "undefined"!

Input element in the form is:

```
<input name="Address" type="text" maxlength="255"  id="Address" class="required address"  onchange="detectPO();" />
```

My script so far is:

```
<script>
function detectPO() { 
    var StreetAddress = document.getElementById('Address').value;
    console.log("You entered: " + StreetAddress);
}
</script>
```

I've scoured dozens of similar sounding questions on here, and searched on google. I'm really trying. Based on all I've read, this should work, no? But it does not. Tried console in both Chrome and FF.

Can anyone help me? Much appreciation for all efforts.

Comment: I think you have to double escape the backslashes in the RegEx constructor.

Comment: `"\b"` is a BACKSPACE char. `"\\b"` is a *word boundary*. Use `var RegEx = /^(?:Post(?:al)? (?:Office )?|P[. ]?O\.? )?Box\b/;`

Comment: he said he is getting the `StreetAddress` is `undefined`

Comment: Check for duplicate ids. console.log the `document.getElementById('Address')` itself and see whether it is the element you are looking for

Comment: @NithinChandran: Genius! I had copied an existing form from elsewhere, and based on your tip, I looked, and lo and behold, someone had put matching ID's on the TR's! Unbelievable! I feel sheepish. Trying again. Thank you!!

Comment: @DougJoseph happy to help